# Django extracting values and making them placeholders in another page

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, python-3.x

so on my first webpage I have a submit button that contains an array of information I need in the value tag.

```
<button type="submit" name="editEntry" value="[{{ entry.id }}, {{ entry.first_name }}, {{ entry.last_name }}, {{ entry.country }}, {{ entry.city }}, {{ entry.salary }}]">Edit</button>
```

In my view.py, I set variables for each extracted information in the value tag.

```
def post(self, request):
    form = AddUser(request.POST or None)

    context = { 'form': form }
    if 'editEntry' in request.POST:
        values = request.POST['editEntry']
        id_num = values[0]
        first_name = values[1]
        last_name = values[2]
        country = values[3]
        city = values[4]
        salary = values[5]

    return redirect('/edit')
```

Now in my edit page I have a some input tags

```
<input type="hidden" name="id_num" value="">
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="">
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="">
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="">
<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" value="">
<input type="text" name="salary" placeholder="salary" value="">
```

How can I take the variables, I gained from my first webpage, and put them as the values in my input tags for the edit page?

Answer (score 0):

Since post django 1.2 you can not pass context with redirect. There is a **hack** you can do. I am not a huge fan of this.

def post(self, request):
    form = AddUser(request.POST or None)

```
context = { 'form': form }
if 'editEntry' in request.POST:
    values = request.POST['editEntry']
    id_num = values[0]
    first_name = values[1]
    last_name = values[2]
    country = values[3]
    city = values[4]
    salary = values[5]
    redirect_url = '/edit?'+'value='+values+'&id_num='+id_num+'&first_name='+first_name+'&last_name='+last_name+'&country='+country+'&city='+city+'&salary='+salary 
    return redirect(redirect_url)
```

This is the idea. Please check the url is getting formed correctly. Once you have these in url you can easily extract them as follows:

```
function get_url_params(param){
    main_dict={}
    arr=window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&') 
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
        main_dict[arr[i].split('=')[0]] = arr[i].split('=')[1];
    }
    return main_dict[param])
}
```

after defining this function you can do:

```
var first_name = get_url_params('first_name');
document.getElementsByName('first_name')[0].value = first_name
```

Do this for rest of the params.

Comment: So how do I extract the redirect url information to put in the input value tag? Also is there a way to do this in django 1.3?

Comment: window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&')  this would give you array of key value pairs. split each element of that array to grab key  and value.

Comment: function get_url_params(param){
 main_dict={}
//     console.log(param);
 arr=window.location.href.split('?')[1].split('&') 
 for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
  main_dict[arr[i].split('=')[0]] = arr[i].split('=')[1];
    }
    console.log(main_dict);
 console.log(main_dict[param]);
}

Comment: above function can help you in fetching the param. exmaple: get_url_param('country');

Comment: Anyway to do this with the template language?

Comment: This is the way I am aware of. I have updated the answer as well.

Comment: That being said, then would actually go in the value option in '<input value="">

Comment: Also, is there a way to do this with sessions?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to pass some values from one page to another, the `request.sessions` would be the best solution.

```
def post(self, request):
    form = AddUser(request.POST or None)
    request.session['form_detail'] = {}  # create session
    context = { 'form': form }
    if 'editEntry' in request.POST:
        values = request.POST['editEntry']
        request.session['form_detail']['id_num'] = values[0]
        request.session['form_detail']['first_name'] = values[1]
        request.session['form_detail']['last_name'] = values[2]
        request.session['form_detail']['country'] = values[3]
        request.session['form_detail']['city'] = values[4]
        request.session['form_detail']['salary'] = values[5]

    return redirect('/edit')
```

then in template you can call these values stored in session with

```
{% with session=request.session.form_detail %}
<input type="hidden" name="id_num" value="{{ session.id_num }}">
<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="{{ session.first_name }}">
<input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="{{ session.last_name }}">
<input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" value="{{ session.city }}">
<input type="text" name="country" placeholder="Country" value="{{ session.country }}">
<input type="text" name="salary" placeholder="salary" value="{{ session.salary }}">
{% endwith %}
```